# SSRS subscription throwing Invalid State error when saving

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, subscription

I have migrated to a new report server. When trying to create new subscriptions through the URL I am getting the following error:

```
Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
```

I found that a certain windows KB can cause this issue (KB2656356 and KB2656351) However I have found that adding a key to the web.config file might also do the trick.

```
<https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/cb6ede72-6ed1-   4379-9d3c-847c11b75b32/report-manager-operation-cannot-run-due-to-current-state-   of-the-object?forum=sqlreportingservices/>
```

But after adding this key and bouncing the services, no change. I still get the error. Has anyone experienced this?

```
ui!ReportManager_0-1!5144!03/21/2017-10:23:17:: e ERROR: System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection()
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form()
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_HasForm()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.GetCollectionBasedOnMethod(Boolean dontReturnNull)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.DeterminePostBackMode()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
library!ReportServer_0-2!5e0!03/21/2017-10:23:18:: i INFO: Call to GetSystemPermissionsAction().
ui!ReportManager_0-1!5144!03/21/2017-10:23:18:: e ERROR: HTTP status code --> 500
-------Details--------
System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

    at System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection()

    at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form()

    at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_HasForm()

    at System.Web.UI.Page.GetCollectionBasedOnMethod(Boolean dontReturnNull)

    at System.Web.UI.Page.DeterminePostBackMode()

    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
 library!ReportServer_0-2!5e0!03/21/2017-10:23:18:: i INFO: Call to GetSystemPropertiesAction().
 ui!ReportManager_0-1!5144!03/21/2017-10:23:18:: e ERROR: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
    at System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal()
    at System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo)
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.End()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.ReportingPage.ShowErrorPage(String errMsg)
```

The SSRS version is 11.0.3000.0. It is a native install. I am creating the subscription through the report server URL "businessreport/reports";. It seems directly related to the amount of available parameters. In my case if I pair down the amount of items including the report, then I don't have an issue. Obviously i can edit the report to fix this, but I inherited a very large amount of reports. I'd rather be able to pass as many as necessary. Hopefully that helps

Also I have tried editing the web.config file in both of the following directories:

```
I:\MSRS11.SQLPROD\Reporting Services\ReportManager
```

and
    I:\MSRS11.SQLPROD\Reporting Services\ReportServer

I included the following:  This did not make a difference at all.

Comment: Having more details about your environment would be helpful. What version of SSRS are you using? Is it installed in native or integrated mode? Where are you creating the subscription, in Report Manager?

Comment: The SSRS version is 11.0.3000.0. It is a native install. I am creating the subscription through the report server URL "http://businessreport/reports". It seems directly related to the amount of available parameters. In my case if I pair down the amount of items including the report, then I don't have an issue. Obviously i can edit the report to fix this, but I inherited a very large amount of reports. I'd rather be able to pass as many as necessary. Hopefully that helps.